# Odd looping situation, don't know what's causing it

Tags: c++, loops, infinite

Having some trouble with some code and I cannot get to the bottom of it.  This code:

```
int main()
{
int choice;

while (choice != -1)
{
      system("cls");
      std::cout << "Main Menu: " << std::endl
                << " 1. Encode." << std::endl
                << " 2. Decode." << std::endl
                << "-1 to exit." << std::endl;

      std::cin >> choice;

      switch (choice)
      {
             case 1:
                  encode();
                  break;
             case 2:
                  decode();
                  break;
             case -1:
                  break;
      }
}

getchar();
return 0;

}

void encode()
{
 std::string plainText;
 std::string encText = "Test";

 std::cout << "Enter text to be encrypted.\n";

 getline(std::cin, plainText);

 for (int x = 0; x < plainText.length(); x++)
 {
     //encText += plainText.substr(x, x + 1);
 }

 std::cout << encText;
 getchar();

 return;
}
```

If I enter '1' at the first cin >> choice, I go into encode(), once there, entering any text causes the program to go back to the while, perform system("cls"), and then jumps right back to "Enter text to be encrypted." down in encode().

Any help? I'm clueless.

Comment: Any of these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=getline+skipping

Comment: What is the point of `getchar()` at the end of `encode()`?

Comment: @kefkamaydie: Here is a puzzle :-), what would happen if user chooses to enter '0' as input choice? Think about it :-)

Comment: Thanks guys. Answer was indeed provided in another question!

Comment: The point of the getchar() at the end of encode was just to keep the system("cls") from firing before I could see if the input was taken.

Comment: I think Arun Saha has figured it out. If you enter "-1", the "-" sign is eaten by the getchar() call, so that two-letter entry treated as a "1" by the main loop and encode() gets called.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to exit your `while` loop after `encode()` or `decode()`, you have to satisty the `while`'s condition.  You can do this by simple setting `choice` to `-1` after the function calls:

```
         case 1:
              encode();
              choice = -1;
              break;
         case 2:
              decode();
              choice = -1;
              break;
```

Just so you're aware, the `return` at the end of `encode()` causes the `encode()` function to finish, not `main`.  That line of code actually does nothing; since there's nothing after it, it would happen anyway.